# Why can std::rc::Rc call its own value's methods?

Tags: rust, type-systems

I'm a newbie to Rust and type-systems. I'm reading [rustc/rc.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/liballoc/rc.rs). I don't know why `Rc<T>` can call T's methods. What conditions does **`a Structure<T>`** satisfy for calling methods of the wrapped value?

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new("The quick fox".to_string());
    println!("{}", a.contains("white")); // Rc<String> can call String#contains.
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This property is called "[`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)".

If you have two types `T` and `U`, such that `T: Deref<Target = U>`, then everywhere you have a `&T`, you can *coerce* it to `&U`. In particular, as method call syntax is just sugar to the functions taking `&self` (or `&mut self`, or `self` - depending on the method), you can call methods on the `U` having only `T`.

As you can see in the docs, [`Deref` is implemented for `Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-20), as it is for almost any other smart pointer (the "active" smart pointers like `Mutex`, which involve explicit locking, being notable exception). So, when you have one of these smart pointers, you can treat a reference to it as the reference to the inner value - see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o) about other consequences of this fact.

More info on this topic could be also found [in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html).

Comment: so basically the compiler knows what types are smart pointers and the compiler writes `(*a).contains("white")` automatically? can i implement deref on my custom type? and then call its inner type methods without writing `*object` everytime?

Comment: Of course you can. Other then these auth-inserted coercions, `Deref` is an ordinary trait, which can be implemented on arbitrary types (modulo orphan rules, of course).

Comment: i didnt ask if you can implement the trait, i asked if you get auto deref without writing `*` after implemeting the trait

Comment: This is not called "`Deref` coercion" but "autoderef". `Deref` coercion is for example when you do `let v: &String = &rc`.

Answer (score 0):

im writing this answer for people who want to implement their custom type that has an inner type and then call the inner's type methods without writing wrapper functions.

this is a handy situation for struct composition/aggregation, where you have a wrapper over a type and dont want to write every method like this:

```rust
pub fn width(&self) -> i32 {
    self.inner.width()
}

pub fn height(&self) -> i32 {
    self.inner.height()
}
/// and so on ...
```

this is actually ugly and annoying. imagine if you have 100 methods to wrap ...

here's the small example:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

pub struct Inner {}

impl Inner {
    pub fn just_a_method(&self) -> i32 {
        32
    }
}

struct DerefExample<T> {
    inner: T,
}

impl<T> Deref for DerefExample<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.inner
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = DerefExample {
        inner: Inner {}
    };
    let result = (*x).just_a_method();
    println!("(*x).just_a_method() == {}", result);
    let result = x.just_a_method();
    println!("x.just_a_method() == {}", result);
}
```

note that both methods of calling the `just_a_method` work the same. the second time the compiler automatically dereferences the `x` to get the inner type.

program output:

```bash
(*x).just_a_method() == 32
x.just_a_method() == 32
```